# CodeIgniter -> php spark serve Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just created a new project with CodeIgniter.
I tried to run this command to run the server:

```
php spark serve
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/mnt/e/dev/learning/php/codeigniter/001/app/Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /mnt/e/dev/learning/php/codeigniter/001/spark on line 44
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/mnt/e/dev/learning/php/codeigniter/001/app/Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /mnt/e/dev/learning/php/codeigniter/001/spark on line 44
```

How can I run this command

Comment: were you ever able to figure out a remedy? I'm running PHP > 7.2 as noted in answer below, but also hitting this issue right out of the gate with a fresh install of CI. Do I need to add in a bootstrap package to get server to start?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP version 7.2 or newer is required, with the `intl` extension and `mbstring` extension installed.
The following PHP extensions should be enabled on your server: `php-json, php-mysqlnd, php-xml`

And then follow below steps to install and run CI 4 project:

- `composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root`
- `composer clearcache`
- `composer update`
- Config Setting:baseUrl in *app/Config/App.php* and DB info in *app/Config/Database.php*
- `php spark serve`

Note: clear composer cache before updating composer. For detail info follow [CI documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/installing_composer.html)

Comment: once followed your flows, I can see the app is running. but when I check this url http://localhost:8080/ it's not working

Comment: ```PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Config\App" not found in E:\projects\ci\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Factories.php:126```
I am facing this error. What could be the reason? I tried all possible solutions, but none of them worked. Note: I am using PHP 8.1.6

Comment: create a new empty project with composer/codeigniter and compare the systems files between projects. move the new project files to your project. once I have this problem when upgrading from a specific version of CI4

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to upgrade my CI setup, and all files I didn't adapt I thought I could easily copy them to retrieve the latest file. Like: `cp vendor/codeigniter4/framework/app/Config/Constants.php ./app/Config/`

However, I did the same for the `app/Config/Paths.php` file, but that resulted in your error message as well.

Bottom-line: don't try to replace the `Paths.php` file from upstream. And the `$systemDirectory` variable in `Paths.php` should look like this:

```
public $systemDirectory = __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system';
```